# Enumerable topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a non-empty, fixed set $x_{0} \in X$ arbitrary. Show that $B = \{\{x\}: x \in X\backslash\{x_0\}\} \cup \{A\subseteq X: x_0\in A$ e $X\backslash A$ is enumerable $\}$ is a base for a topology over $X$.

Be $X$ a set and $B$ a collection of subsets of $X$ satisfying the following properties:

(1) For each $U_1$, $U_2$ and each $x\in U_1\cap U_2$, there is $U\in B$ such that $x \in U\subseteq U_1\cap U_2$.

(2) For each $x\in X$, there is $U\in B$ such as $x\in U$.

So the $B^{\ast}$, formed by the $B$ subcollection unions, is a topology about $X$ and $B$ is a basis for the $(X,B^{\ast})$topological space.

How can I prove that given $U_1$ and $U_2$ and a point at the intersection then there is $U$ at the intersection, such as $x$ is at $U$ ? My questions are whether I $U_1$ and $U_2$ arbitrary?

Also, how can I show (2), which always exists $x\in X$, is there $U\in B$ such that $x\in U$?

Comment: $X$ is in the second part of that base. $X\setminus X$ is empty so at most countable. That implies property 2.

Comment: If you take $A$ such that $X\setminus A$ is infinitely countable it is still true (if $X$ is infinite) since for every $x\neq x_0$ $\{x\}\in B$, and since $X\setminus \{x_0\}$ is infinite this means (assuming AC) that there is a countable subset $A$ of $X\setminus \{x_0\}$, $x_0\in A^c$ and $X\setminus A^c$ is countable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove something stronger, that is $U_1\cap U_2\in B\cup\{\varnothing\}$. Take $U_i\in B$, $i=1,2$, this means that either $U_i=\{x\}$ or $X\setminus U_1$ is enumerable, this gives you three cases:

$U_1=\{x_1\}, U_2=\{x_2\}$, this means that either $U_1\cap U_2=\varnothing$, or $x_1=x_2$ wich means $U_1=U_2=U_1\cap U_2$.

$U_1=\{x\}$, $X\setminus U_2$ is enumerable, then $U_1\cap U_2=\varnothing$ if $x\notin U_2$ or $U_1\cap U_2=U_1$ if $x\in U_2$.

$X\setminus U_1$ and $X\setminus U_2$ are enumerable, then $X\setminus (U_1\cap U_2)=(X\setminus U_1)\cup (X\setminus U_2)$, since the union of two enumerable sets is enumerable you are finished.

Comment: And the property (2) how to prove it?

Comment: every $x$ is in $X$ (obviously), and $X\in B$ since $X\setminus X=\varnothing$ and $\varnothing$ is enumerable.